# Remove #location from url using jquery when redirecting in php

Tags: php, jquery

I have an html mail form that is at the bottom of the page. My php redirects back to the bottom of the page like so:

```
header('Location: index.html#social');
```

It redirects fine and puts me back at the bottom of the screen but the url then becomes

```
/index.html#social
```

I want to remove the #social (and the index.html if possible, but not a big deal) from the url.

Currently I use this function in jquery:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e) {
    history.replaceState("", document.title, e.originalEvent.oldURL);
});
```

which works for all of my other hashchanges in the html, but that doesn't seem to work on php hash redirects. Any suggestions? I can't seem to find anything else with the same issue.

Comment: location.hash = '';

Comment: I would put that in my js/jquery file? When I try that it redirects to the top of the page instead of the bottom and still doesn't remove the hash.

Comment: The problem is that your `hashchange` handler is scrolling when you remove the hash. Don't use both of them.

Comment: why not redirect to just `/`, then? if you don't want the hash, then don't send it in the first place.

Comment: Because then it won't redirect to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation I figured it out.

I added this to my jquery after my hashchange function:

```
history.replaceState("", document.title, "/");
```